# Grunt Watch Task Livereload Option to Point to Express Server Causes "watch.livereload.files" missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am building a Gruntfile.js file by hand for the learning experience. With the logic I have in this, if one of the static html/css/js files changes I want the express server to reload. So, in the watch task I have a livereload option to reload the express by pointing it to the express server task with `livereload: '<%= express %>'`. However, it's not working out as planned and I get:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Verifying property watch.livereload.files exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "watch.livereload.files" missing.
```

I get this message scrolling contentiously until grunt eventually breaks. What is causing this and how do I have it to where it would bounce express upon one of the static files changing? I would rather keep the express task outside of watch task and just reference it in watch task to keep it cleaner looking.

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        express: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                script: 'app.js'
                }
            },

        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },

            servedFiles: {
                files: '<%= pkg.name %>/static/**',
                options: {
                  livereload: true
                }
            },

            livereload: {
                options: {
                  livereload: '<%= express %>'
                  }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'start server', function(target) {
        grunt.task.run('watch');
        console.log("ssss");
        grunt.task.run('express');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I included a files property with a list of files in options under livereload which fixed the error. With that being said, this is not going to bounce express and the best way is just the standard way as a task(make sure to use spawn: false).